# Issue with the supabase initalization before calling Supabase.instance during unit testing

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, mocking, supabase

I'm trying to do unit test on one of the functions in a cubit. The error says that Supabase was not initalized before calling Supabase.instance.

Supabase is used for authentication via google OAuth, access token and storing of data in db.

This is the testing code.

```
void main() {
  late MockTeamHomeRepository mockTeamHomeRepository;
  late TeamHomeCubit teamHomeCubit;

  group("getTeamHomeData()", () {
    setUp(() async {
      mockTeamHomeRepository = MockTeamHomeRepository();
      teamHomeCubit = TeamHomeCubit(AuthRepository(Supabase.instance),
          TeamRepository(), UserRepository(Supabase.instance));
    });

    blocTest<TeamHomeCubit, TeamHomeState>(
      'Cubit should emit the state that changes isLeading to true.',
      build: () => teamHomeCubit,
      act: (cubit) => cubit.setIsLeadingState(true),
      expect: () => [const TeamHomeState(isLeading: true)],
    );
  });
}
```

```
_AssertionError ('package:supabase_flutter/src/supabase.dart': Failed assertion: line 32 pos 7: '_instance._initialized': You must initialize the supabase instance before calling Supabase.instance)
```

The cubit requires repositories that require the Supabase.instance, so I could not start testing any codes thus far.

I've tried to create a fake Supabase similar to this, but failed to integrate it with my testing code. So, the same error persists.

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:supabase/supabase.dart';

void main() {
  test('Fake Supabase', () async {
    final supabase = FakeSupabase();

    final response = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword(
      email: 'test@gmail.com',
      password: 'passsword',
    );
    expect(response.session, isA<Session>());
  });
}

class FakeSupabase extends Fake implements SupabaseClient {
  @override
  get auth => FakeGotrue();
}

class FakeGotrue extends Fake implements GoTrueClient {
  final _user = User(
    id: 'id',
    appMetadata: {},
    userMetadata: {},
    aud: 'aud',
    createdAt: DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
  );
  @override
  Future<AuthResponse> signInWithPassword(
      {String? email,
      String? phone,
      required String password,
      String? captchaToken}) async {
    return AuthResponse(
      session: Session(
        accessToken: '',
        tokenType: '',
        user: _user,
      ),
      user: _user,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, show us code where you use the FakeSupabase instance in the test "Cubit should emit the state that changes isLeading to true"

Comment: @LuisUtrera Hi, that's the main issue I'm facing, where I'm having issue creating the FakeSupabase instance for the testing code.

Comment: I honestly need help with a similar problem too

Answer (score -1):

It's a test, so you shouldn't need a real Supabase instance. Just mock the `AuthRepository` as well.

```dart
void main() {
  late MockTeamHomeRepository mockTeamHomeRepository;
  late TeamHomeCubit teamHomeCubit;
  late AuthRepository mockAuthRepository;

  group("getTeamHomeData()", () {
    setUp(() async {
      mockTeamHomeRepository = MockTeamHomeRepository();
      mockAuthRepository = MockAuthRepository();
      teamHomeCubit = TeamHomeCubit(AuthRepository(Supabase.instance),
          TeamRepository(), mockAuthRepository);
    });

    blocTest<TeamHomeCubit, TeamHomeState>(
      'Cubit should emit the state that changes isLeading to true.',
      build: () => teamHomeCubit,
      act: (cubit) => cubit.setIsLeadingState(true),
      expect: () => [const TeamHomeState(isLeading: true)],
    );
  });
}
```